# Datetime object won't work with weekday()

Tags: python, django

```
class Event(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    period = models.IntegerField(choices=period_choices)
    cart = models.CharField(choices=cart_choice, max_length=4)
    is_reserved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

class ReservationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('day', 'teacher', 'is_reserved', 'period', 'cart')
        widgets = {'teacher': forms.HiddenInput(), 'is_reserved': forms.HiddenInput(), 'period': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'cart': forms.HiddenInput(), 'day': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

I want to get the day of the week in order to sort events. I should be able to do this using Django's date filter - `{% field.initial.day|day:"w" %}` - but that doesn't return anything.

So I wrote a template tag:

```
@register.filter
def the_day(value):
    return value.date().weekday()

home.html
{{ form.initial.day|the_day }}
```

Nope: **'str' object has no attribute 'date'**

Alright, let's use dateparse

```
@register.filter
def the_day(value):
    answer = parse_date(value)
    return answer.weekday()
```

Nope: **Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: expected string or bytes-like object**

Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use [django's inbuilt date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

**Edit:**

I am guessing you need week day in number,

```
{{ form.initial.day|date:"w" }}
```

Or if you want weekday name  template tag

```
{{ form.initial.day|date:"D" }}
```

Comment: I did that! Thank you! But it doesn't work as a conditonal:  `{% if form.initial.day|date:"w" = 5 %}` returns nothing

Comment: Got it! The inbuilt date is a string, not an integer. `{% with d=form.initial.day|date:"w" %}  {% if d == '5' %}`

Comment: Yes, same variable type needed when comparing them.